# Many of joomla websites on my server have been hacked; no other kind of website

Tags: security, centos5, hacking, joomla

Today I got that many of `Joomla` websites on my server are hacked.

- Some of the hacked joomlas were updated (the last version from 2.5 series) with the last version.
- In many cases, the **main index.php** were hacked **(not the index.php of their templates)**.
- Not ALL the joomla sites were hacked.
- The hosting control panel is Directadmin
- Centos's root password and Directadmin's admin password and the main reseller's password are strong enough.
- **For each joomla, all user's passwords were changed.**
- For one of the sites, the whole `images` folder were completely deleted.

The hacker might have let some backdoors for himself.

Previously this had happened, but since a very long time (about more than a year) this hadn't been occurred.

What should I do to make my server stronger enough? Is that very common?

I think that it's now the problem of the server, not the problem of each joomla site.

Comment: Please consider that a very important point is `Joomla`. It looks a duplicate question from some aspects, but it is not an `EXACT DUPLICATE` because of its specifications.

Comment: It's impossible to provide an answer for every single hack on Sf, so there's a "catch-all" question with good tips.

Answer (score -1):

These are some tips for your solution

Security Tips :

- Change SSH port from 22 to another.
- In DA control panel , login as Admin Level->Administrator Settings->Blacklist IPs for excessive DA login attempts..  set it to smaller than 10.
- Change your mysql administration password and limit other users.
- Do not use same password for your ssh , DA etc.
- An antivirus is a good choice to block hackers.
- If you have iptables on your centos , be sure that your configuration is strong.
- Shared hosting have lots of defects and you have to monitor and check processes some times.

Although maybe this problem is for joomla security!

Comment: -1. The first step would be nuking the server from orbit, with network off, and then rebuilding from backups (and patching recent vulnerabilities like [CVE-2013-1455](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-1455). Only after that can you apply hardening tips.